# When running a dataflow Pipeline how can I reuse VMS

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using a Dataflow pipeline on GCP to insert data into BigQuery. However, every time I run it, it creates a new VM for the job. What I want is to run multiple jobs but reuse VMs. For example, instead of creating a new VM, I'd like to specify a VM instance name for it to use that instance instead of creating a new one. Alternatively, it would be great if it could automatically recognize that the job is from Dataflow and reuse a VM for Dataflow jobs.

To run the pipeline I´m using the following command:

```
python3 -m PositionData-rcv-pipe \
  --project=$GCP_PROJECT \
  --region=$REGION \
  --input_topic=projects/$GCP_PROJECT/topics/$TOPIC_ID \
  --output_path=gs://$BUCKET_NAME/samples/output \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --worker-pool=$WORKERS_POOL \
  --max_parallelism=2 \
  --num_workers=1 \
  --max_num_workers=3 \
  --experiments=use_sibling_sdk_workers \
  --window_size=10 \
  --num_shards=12 \
  --job_name position \
  --setup_file ./setup.py \
  --staging_location gs://$BUCKET_NAME/staging \
  --temp_location gs://$BUCKET_NAME/temp \
  --service_account_email=$API_SA \
  --machine_type=n1-standard-1 \
  --reuse_nodes=True \
  --vm_reuse=True \
  --number_of_worker_harness_threads=6 \
  --reuseWorkerHarness=True \
 # --update
#  --extra_package dist/package_proto-0.1.tar.gz \

export GOOGLE_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_VM_REUSE=True
```

What I am expecting is that if I have two Dataflow jobs, they use the same VM for both instead of creating a separate VM for each job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create one big pipeline that contains all the job graph and run it with a single Dataflow job.

Comment: So, this way I can´t reuse VMs for other jobs not related with dataflow, I´m also searching for optimization in cost, VM reuse, it´s one way to archive it

Comment: You cannot reuse VMs for other non Dataflow jobs. You could try Dataflow Prime to optimize the cost. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-costs-for-dataflow-batch-and-streaming-data-processing has more information.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the scaling nature of resource allocation in Dataflow, I believe this is not a setting that is applicable at the moment.

Reference:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/overview#scalable

I am not sure if applicable to your use case, but you can try [custom image containers.](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers)